# Is there a single Drush and or Drupal console command to export and import all configurations?

Tags: drush, configuration, console

Normally I goto Config Sync then export all > save config tar.gz > import.

Can this be achieved with one command?

Comment: Have you looked it up? Google, docs, code, anything? With what search request? What did you search for? What have you found so far and what exactly is still unclear with these search results?

Comment: Brutal down votes.  I guess my question didn't express my confusion with with how through UI you export then import but the command to do the same is drush cex.  Originally I understood that command to only "config export" similar to the UI option.

Answer (score 2):

Drush has two commands. cex and cim, for export and import.

Example:

`drush cim`

Comment: https://drushcommands.com

Answer (score 1):

To export config use:

```
drush cex
```

@see https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-export/

---

To import config use:

```
drush cim
```

@see https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-import/